# Google Distance Matrix API - Error = "HTTPError: HTTP Error: 400"

Tags: python, json, google-maps-api-3

**Goal:**

- Return drive times for 99 individual (I am starting with one,'Origins' and 'Destinations' to assure I have the format correct),'Origins' and 'Destinations' in JSON format.

However, I receive the following error: " HTTPError: HTTP Error: 400"

Overall, I am using Python 2.7, and this is my initial API attempt, so any assistance on the cause is greatly appreciated!

FYI: I am using the following GitHub as blueprint to structure my code:
https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python/blob/master/googlemaps/distance_matrix.py

**Code:**

```
import googlemaps
from googlemaps import convert
from googlemaps.convert import as_list


#API key
key = 'xxxxx'
client = googlemaps.Client(key)


#establishes: drive duration, english, non-metric measurements
def distance_matrix(client, origins, destinations,
                    mode="driving", language="en", avoid=None, units="imperial",
                    departure_time="calendar.timegm(time.gmtime())", arrival_time=None, transit_mode=None,transit_routing_preference=None):

    #establishes "origin" and "destinations" geoInfo via the .json structure
    params = {
    "origins": '1218 3rd St, Santa Monica, 90401, CA',
    "destinations": '90278'
}

    if mode:
        # NOTE(broady): the mode parameter is not validated by the Maps API
        # server. Check here to prevent silent failures.
        if mode not in ["driving", "walking", "bicycling", "transit"]:
            raise ValueError("Invalid travel mode.")
        params["mode"] = mode

    if language:
        params["language"] = language

    if avoid:
        if avoid not in ["tolls", "highways", "ferries"]:
            raise ValueError("Invalid route restriction.")
        params["avoid"] = avoid

    if units:
        params["units"] = units

    if departure_time:
        params["departure_time"] = convert.time(departure_time)

    if arrival_time:
        params["arrival_time"] = convert.time(arrival_time)

    if departure_time and arrival_time:
        raise ValueError("Should not specify both departure_time and"
                         "arrival_time.")

    if transit_mode:
        params["transit_mode"] = convert.join_list("|", transit_mode)

    if transit_routing_preference:
        params["transit_routing_preference"] = transit_routing_preference

    return client._get("/maps/api/distancematrix/json", params)


print distance_matrix(client, "origins", "destinations")
```

**Complete Error Message Traceback:**

```
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-3127b996dc24> in <module>()
     58 
     59 
---> 60 print distance_matrix(client, "origins", "destinations")
     61 

<ipython-input-23-3127b996dc24> in distance_matrix(client, origins, destinations, mode, language, avoid, units, departure_time, arrival_time, transit_mode, transit_routing_preference)
     55         params["transit_routing_preference"] = transit_routing_preference
     56 
---> 57     return client._get("/maps/api/distancematrix/json", params)
     58 
     59 

C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\googlemaps\client.pyc in _get(self, url, params, first_request_time, retry_counter, base_url, accepts_clientid, extract_body)
    179             if extract_body:
    180                 return extract_body(resp)
--> 181             return self._get_body(resp)
    182         except googlemaps.exceptions._RetriableRequest:
    183             # Retry request.

C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\googlemaps\client.pyc in _get_body(self, resp)
    187     def _get_body(self, resp):
    188         if resp.status_code != 200:
--> 189             raise googlemaps.exceptions.HTTPError(resp.status_code)
    190 
    191         body = resp.json()

HTTPError: HTTP Error: 400
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Google's documentation when you get a 400 Response code it could be either a **Invalid Parameter** or a **badRequest**. In case of:

**Invalid Parameter:** Indicates that a request parameter has an invalid value. The locationType and location fields in the error response provide information as to which value was invalid.

Do not retry without fixing the problem. You need to provide a valid value for the parameter specified in the error response.

**Bad Request:** Indicates that the query was invalid. E.g., parent ID was missing or the combination of dimensions or metrics requested was not valid.

Do not retry without fixing the problem. You need to make changes to the API query in order for it to work.

I think the issue is with the API key. You can make use of the Direction API if you do not request for a quota even without a API_KEY. And in the sample code provided in code I cannot see API_KEY being put in the client parameter.

```
#API key
key = 'xxxxx'
client = googlemaps.Client(key)
```

Try removing this.